# Solve inhomogeneous Poisson's equation, gives no result at all

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve the following two-dimensional inhomogeneous Poisson's equation in Mathematica including specific boundary conditions, and I know that an analytical solution exists, but Mathematica is not cooperating in this special case.

I would like to analytically solve the following Poisson's equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=6 x (1-y) y-2 x^3$$
with the boundary conditions
$$u(0, y)=0,\ u(1, y)=(1-y)y,\ u(x, 0)=0,\ u(x, 1)=0$$
From a textbook I know that the solution is
$$u(x,y)=y(1-y)x^3$$
If I try to solve this equation system by using `DSolve`

```
DSolve[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == -2 x^3 + 6 x (1 - y) y,
 u[0, y] == 0, 
 u[1, y] == (1 - y) y, 
 u[x, 0] == 0, 
 u[x, 1] == 0}, u, {x, y}]
```

But *Mathematica* refused to do anything and is not returning any error message at all. Am I overlooking something or is such an PDE not solvable analytically in *Mathematica*?

Of course one could use `NDSolve`, but I would like to have the possibility to get more general solutions through `DSolve`.

Comment: [This doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html) says: *DSolve can find the general solution for a restricted type of homogeneous linear second-order PDEs; namely, equations of the form* `a*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + b*D[u[x, y], x, y] + c*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0`. Your equation has a nonvanishing non-principal part, and the algorithm used by DSolve is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DSolve` is not equipped to solve this but it's pretty easy to solve.  Given a polynomial $f$, you wish to find $u$ such that 
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = f(x,y),$$
together with polynomial boundary conditions on a square.
It seems reasonably clear $u$ should be a multi-variate polynomial, so let's write down the general fifth degree multi-variate polynomial and interpret the PDE and boundary conditions as algebraic conditions on the coefficients.

Here are $f$ and $u$ defined in Mathematica.

```
Clear[f,u];
f[x_,y_] = 6x(1-y)y-2x^3;
u[x_,y_] = Sum[a[n,j]x^(n-j) y^j,{n,0,5},{j,0,n}]
```

[image]

Now, the PDE $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = f(x,y)$, can be expressed in terms of the coefficients.  For example, the coefficient of $x^3$ in $f$ is $-2$.  The same coefficient in $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ can be found as follows:

```
Coefficient[D[u[x,y],x,x]+D[u[x,y],y,y],x^3]
```

[image]

Thus, we have $20a_{5,0}+2a_{5,2} = -2$.  This is just one of a system of equations that must be satisfied.  We can grab them all as follows.

```
rhs = Tuples[{Range[0,3],Range[0,3]}] /. 
  Append[CoefficientRules[6x(1-y)y-2x^3,{x,y}],{_,_} -> 0];
lhs = Tuples[{Range[0,3],Range[0,3]}] /. 
  Append[CoefficientRules[D[u[x,y],x,x]+D[u[x,y],y,y],{x,y}],{_,_} -> 0];
eqs = Thread[lhs==rhs]
```

[image]

The `True`s are a bit superfluous but don't hurt anything.  Let's redefine $u$ by solving this system and plugging the resulting coefficients back into $u$.

```
u[x_,y_] = u[x,y] /. First[Solve[eqs]]
```

[image]

Note now that number of unknowns has been reduced - $a_{5,5}$, for example, appears three times.  If this worked, then the following should be exactly $f(x,y)$.

```
D[u[x,y],x,x]+D[u[x,y],y,y]//Expand
```

[image]

Now, the solution can be narrowed down further using the boundary conditions.  Consider, for example, $u(0,y)=0$:

```
u[0,y]
```

[image]

This is a polynomial in $y$ and can only equal zero if *all* the coefficients are zero. Thus, all the above coefficients must be zero.  The same is true of $u(x,0)$ and $u(x,1)$.  This quickly yields a huge reduction.

```
furtherReduction = #->0& /@ Cases[{u[0,y],u[x,0],u[x,1]},_a,Infinity]
```

[image]

If we plug these in, we should get even closer to the actual solution.

```
u[x,y] /. furtherReduction
```

[image]

In fact, we've already hit it exactly.  Setting $x=1$, it's easy to see that the remaining boundary condition is satisfied.

Comment: perfect analysis. thank you for that. it shows again how well mathematica is suited in the academic study. (+1)

Comment: I'm impressed. Many thanks for this throughout analysis, I appreciate it!